# Executing error in java

Tags: java

> The principal class XXXX has not been found

The code constructs perfectly but when I try to execute it I get the same error again.

I type the following "Hello world" code:

```java
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hola mundo");
    }
}
```

I get the same error.

It must be a problem of my program ,I use GEANY because my teacher told me that I can't use netbean or similar.

Comment: remove public and execute it..

Comment: Please post the **full** error. Paraphrasing is unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

How do you compile and execute your code? Is it some IDE (Eclipse) or just command line?

IDE should take care about this issue. In command line you have to include all classes into the classpath. Sometime it is confusing because when you compile your code mutually is in classpath but you have to mention it litreally to run.

Here is example

```
javac Hello.java
```

compiles Hello.java source to the Hello.class code to the current location. Literally ./Hello.class
To run you should mention this location

```
java -classpath . Hello
```

without **-classpath .** java doesn't know where your class is.

Comment: The programe GEANY has an option ''compile''.I press that button and then the other button of ''execute''.
I´ve tried to compile and execute manually and the same happens.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with GEANY. But you cut&paste exact output (all, including compiling and invoking) of the command line window then I can help.